# Python-BeautifulSoup : How to extract specific text from variable?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to extract only third level category from the breadcrumb "Toys & Hobbies" ?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Mini-remote-control-quadcopter-WiFi-FPV-camera-hd-Pocket-Selfie-Drone-JY018-Easy-carry-travel-hd/32807755975.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.32.60a361b94HcXvC&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_2_10152_5722813_10151_10065_10344_10068_5722613_10342_5722913_10343_10340_10341_10696_10084_10083_5722713_10618_10307_10059_100031_10103_10624_10623_10622_10621_10620_5722513-10620,searchweb201603_2,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=c18e9af6-7eae-465d-8f23-20bf577602e3-3&algo_pvid=c18e9af6-7eae-465d-8f23-20bf577602e3&transAbTest=ae803_1&priceBeautifyAB=0'  
uClient = uReq(my_url)  
page_html = uClient.read()  
uClient.close()  
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")  
description = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "ui-box-body"})  
print(description)
string4 = str(description)
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? What result are you wanting to get?

Comment: It's a breadcrumbs and I need to extract only a category title (Toys &amp; Hobbies) from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming you are just looking for the breadcrumb, which is not where your class suggests, here is a possible solution.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Mini-remote-control-quadcopter-WiFi-FPV-camera-hd-Pocket-Selfie-Drone-JY018-Easy-carry-travel-hd/32807755975.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.32.60a361b94HcXvC&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_2_10152_5722813_10151_10065_10344_10068_5722613_10342_5722913_10343_10340_10341_10696_10084_10083_5722713_10618_10307_10059_100031_10103_10624_10623_10622_10621_10620_5722513-10620,searchweb201603_2,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=c18e9af6-7eae-465d-8f23-20bf577602e3-3&algo_pvid=c18e9af6-7eae-465d-8f23-20bf577602e3&transAbTest=ae803_1&priceBeautifyAB=0'  
uClient = uReq(my_url)  
page_html = uClient.read()  
uClient.close()  
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")  
description = page_soup.find("div", {"class": "ui-breadcrumb"})

for key, link in enumerate(description.findAll('a')):
    if key == 2:
        print(link.text)
```

Note this outputs the only "Toys & Hobbies", key phrase on the page.

Comment: you could replace the last three lines with link = description.find_all('a')[2].text

Comment: That would definitely be cleaner, though i get the feeling this might be more helpful for the questions author.

Comment: Glad I could help.